# Withdraw USDT or BNB from BSC

Tags: web3js, web3j, bsc, usdt, withdrawal

how to withdraw USDT (Tether) or BNB from my wallet to a specific address using the Web3j Java Spring framework on the Binance Smart Chain (BSC)?